# How to assess whether weighted samples come from the same distribution?

Tags: distributions, nonparametric, weighted-sampling

Suppose I have two samples, and I'd like to compare them to see if they come from the same underlying distribution. Normally, I would probably do this using a KS test. However, suppose also that I have some 'weight' for each observation in each of the two samples indicating how 'sure' I am that the sampled value is 'accurate'. In other words, some observations in the samples are more representative of the sampled distribution than others (note that these weights will differ between samples).

With this in mind, my question is: Are there any tests (like a KS test) that I can use to test if these two samples come from the same underlying distribution, taking into account the weights associated with each sample?

Hopefully I'm not being too vague here... but any help and/or comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not  sure why you have these weights, as weights are usually based on the sampling method, which is not your basis for weighting. When you say "same distribution", do you mean (1) both are from a (e.g.) normal distribution, or do you mean (2) both are from a (e.g.) normal distribution with the same statistics (e.g. mean, standard deviation)?

Comment: Thanks for the response @Michelle. In my example, I tried to simplify things a bit in an effort to keep things clear :-p In reality, the weights describe how close a particular sample point is to the coast (i.e., the closer to the coast, the more relevant the sampled point is). To answer your second question, I mean 2 - both are from a given distribution with the same stats.

Comment: That makes sense re the weighing, what does the distribution represent (e.g. height above sea level, NaCl ppm)?

Comment: @Michelle, AFAIK the distribution represents human impact, and is a composite metric which ranges from 1 to 100 (though this is arbitrary).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Michelle I'm curious about how this situation comes about.  But putting that aside, what about putting a bootstrap around a KS test, with the bootstrap resampling based on your weights?  So those points you are more confident about are more likely to get resampled.

Comment: Sounds good @peter, thanks for the suggestion. I'll give it a go, and report back.

Comment: The K-S test is the most well known goodness of fit tests in the class of empirical process tests.  There is a large body of probability theory about empirical processes and weighted empirical processes.  There is also some work on weighted empirical processes in the bootstrap literature.  I don't know if there is a connection between weighted empirical processes and a weighting of data points but that was the first thing that came to mind.

Answer (score 2):

I just had a simple thought that might work.  I assume the weights are known and fixed. Modify the samples to make the distributions look like the weighted distribution. The observations with the smallest weight enter once.  Then an observation with twice that weight gets entered twice etc.  After creating the modified sample apply a standard two sample goodness of fit test. Because the distributions are continuous you could modify this to make the duplicates differ from the original by adding a small random component to each. Now the only problem I see is that every weight have to be an integer multiple of the point(s) with the lowest weights.  To remedy this you could make the lowest weight observations repeat say 5 times.  Then the others could be fractional multiples of the smallest weighted observation.